# Reading a number the second time

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Through the cmd if a user enters the following numbers: `2 -13 4 12 -1 113 19`, the output should be:

```
(2,-13) has signs (+,-) and is in Q4
(4,12) has signs (+,+) and is in Q1
(-1,113) has signs (-,+) and is in Q2
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
(2,-13) has signs (+,-) and is in Q4
(-13,4) has signs (-.+) and is in Q2
(4,12) has signs (+,+) and is in Q1
(12,-1) has signs (+,-) and is in Q4
(-1,113) has signs (-.+) and is in Q2
(113,19) has signs (+,+) and is in Q1
```

i.e. the second number in the pair repeats itself again as the first number in the next consequent pair. Whats wrong with the code?

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
    {

         int[] numbers = new int[args.length];
           try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) 
                {

                    numbers[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i-1]);
                    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                    System.out.println("("+numbers[i-1]+","+numbers[i]+")" + " has signs " + checkSigns(numbers[i-1], numbers[i]) + " and is in " + fromInts(numbers[i-1], numbers[i]));
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increment the variable `i` by `2`, because you using two entries from the array in each iteration of the loop:

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{

     int[] numbers = new int[args.length];
       try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i += 2) 
            {

                numbers[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i-1]);
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                System.out.println("("+numbers[i-1]+","+numbers[i]+")" + "    has signs " + checkSigns(numbers[i-1], numbers[i]) + " and is in " + fromInts(numbers[i-1], numbers[i]));
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your for loop should increment by 2.
because in your case this is what is happening
    numbers[i-1] = 2 where i=1
    numbers[i] = -13 where i=1
    numbers[i-1] = -13 where i=2
    numbers[i] = 4 where i=2 and so on